# How to select only one checkbox in foreach in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to show checkbox in foreach loop but when i click on any one of them all are selected.

How can we separate them.

```
struct Screen: View {

    @State private var checked = true
    var data = ["1","2", "3"]

 var body: some View {
     ForEach( data.indices, id:\.self ) { item in
                HStack {
                CheckBoxView(checked: $checked)
                Text(data[item])
                }
            }
}
 

struct CheckBoxView: View {
    @Binding var checked: Bool

    var body: some View {
        Image(systemName: checked ? "checkmark.square.fill" : "square")
            .foregroundColor(checked ? Color(UIColor.systemBlue) : Color.secondary)
            .onTapGesture {
                self.checked.toggle()
            }
    }
}
```

Thank You for help.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to use an array of state variables:

```swift
struct Screen: View {
    
    @State private var checked: [Bool] = [true, true, true]
    var data = ["1","2", "3"]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach( data.indices, id:\.self ) { index in
                HStack {
                    CheckBoxView(checked: $checked[index])
                    Text(data[index])
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    struct CheckBoxView: View {
        @Binding var checked: Bool
        
        var body: some View {
            Image(systemName: checked ? "checkmark.square.fill" : "square")
                .foregroundColor(checked ? Color(UIColor.systemBlue) : Color.secondary)
                .onTapGesture {
                    self.checked.toggle()
                }
        }
    }
}
```

However, I personally do not like this solution, because the state array is not dynamic in size to your data. With this initialization your state array is always the same size as your data.

```swift
struct Screen: View {
    
    var data = ["1","2", "3"]
    @State private var checked: [Bool]
    
    init() {
        _checked = State(initialValue: [Bool](repeating: false, count: data.count))
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach( data.indices, id:\.self ) { index in
                HStack {
                    CheckBoxView(checked: $checked[index])
                    Text(data[index])
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    struct CheckBoxView: View {
        @Binding var checked: Bool
        
        var body: some View {
            Image(systemName: checked ? "checkmark.square.fill" : "square")
                .foregroundColor(checked ? Color(UIColor.systemBlue) : Color.secondary)
                .onTapGesture {
                    self.checked.toggle()
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: OP would have to fill the rest of the checked array with false values to avoid a Index out of Range error.

Comment: Thank you for answer..that mean i need to maintain one more array?

Comment: I've updated my answer @excitedmicrobe while you were commenting :D

Comment: @Rahul you need to have something to store the checked state with each item.

Comment: Although I'd use a proper data structure that stored the state of selection as well as the item. I suspect the original code isn't the actual code.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer that will allow you to check one or more boxes, and keep track of which values were selected. It uses an .onChanged to keep track of the actual value that has been selected as the check box itself is just UI:

```
struct Screen: View {
    
    var data = ["1","2","3"]
    @State var selectedItems: Set<String> = [] // Use a Set to keep track of multiple check boxes
    @State var selectedItems = "" // Use a String to keep track of only one.

    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach( data, id:\.self ) { item in
                CheckBoxRow(title:item, selectedItems: $selectedItems, isSelected: selectedItems.contains(item))
            }
        }
    }
}

struct CheckBoxRow: View {
    var title: String
    @Binding var selectedItems: Set<String>
    @State var isSelected: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            HStack {
                CheckBoxView(checked: $isSelected, title: title)
                    .onChange(of: isSelected) { _ in
                        if isSelected {
                            selectedItems.insert(title)// or
                            selectedItems = title
                        } else {
                            selectedItems.remove(title)// or
                            selectedItems = ""
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct CheckBoxView: View {
    
    @Binding var checked: Bool
    @State var title: String
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Image(systemName: (checked ? "checkmark.square" : "square"))
            Text(title)
                .padding(.leading)
        }
        .onTapGesture {
            self.checked.toggle()
        }
    }
}
```